# TakeWhile, at least n elements

Tags: c#, linq

There seems to be no `e.TakeWhile(predicate, atLeastNElements)` overload. Is there a convenient way to express *`TakeWhile`, however, take at least `N` elements if there are `>= N` elements available.*?

Edit: the best I came up with in my head is to capture an int in `TakeWhile`'s predicate and reduce it by one each call while returning `true`. The actual predicate is used only after the counter is down to zero.

Comment: Generalized question to N elements, sketched my solution idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an overload to `TakeWhile` with the index of the current element:

```
var e = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var n = 3; // at least n
e.TakeWhile((element, index) => index < n || predicate(element));
```

Comment: You mean `< 3` (i. e. indexes 0, 1 and 2) and you've got the lambda expression parameters the wrong way round - it should be `(value, index)` - but yes, that's basically the way to go.

Comment: Solid! That's better than my counter variable. Like it! (You can accept an answer in 11 minutes...why SO, why?)

Comment: Yes, I do mean `< 3`.

Comment: I improved the answer a little bit more.

Comment: No, you want either the index to be lower than n or predicate to be true.

Comment: @AlexM. No, this would not take at least n elements.

Comment: But this will take the first items even if the predicate is false for them and there are enough positive items wouldn't it?

Comment: It will always include the first three items even when the predicate is false. If you want to prioritize items where predicate is true, you could run `OrderBy(predicate).Take(n)`, or implement it by other means than linq.

Comment: @D.R. With your edit you just made it equivalent to `e.Take(n).Concat(e.Skip(n).TakeWhile(predicate))`. The whole function IMO makes no sense.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Yes, seems to be equivalent, however, runtime-wise Kvam's solution is probably faster. For maximum expressiveness, it should be put into an extension method (`TakeWhileAtLeast`). Your second sentence...don't know what to answer. It makes sense in my domain...

Comment: @D.R. The point was not regrading the performance, I'm not proposing you an answer, and agree for extension method. For the second sentence  - well, it might make sense in your domain, but then the name is misleading. It should be something like, hmm I don't know - `TakeAtLeastConcatWhile` :-) Cheers.